# Does a thread release a lock when it finishes?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have read in places that it isn't good programming practice to acquire a `Lock` object without the code following being enclosed in a `try...finally` block so the lock can be released even if an exception is thrown.

It might sound like a simple question: do all locks belonging to a thread automatically release when the thread finishes?

The reason I ask this question is that the program I am working on is such that once a thread acquires a lock, it should have no reason let it go until it finishes. Additionally, I'm new to using locks, so I'm wondering if there's any pitfalls I may not have considered. Do I have to worry about explicitly releasing locks in my code before the thread finishes, or can I leave it to the JVM, confident in the certain knowledge that other threads being blocked on all the active thread's locks will be activated as soon as the active thread stops?

Comment: Please post some code.

Comment: @C1sc0: Some code about what? The question has a pretty clear problem statement

Comment: You can probably test this with a very simple application. Create two threads, try to aquire the same lock and kill the thread directly after. If the second thread gets the lock it is indeed unlocked.

Comment: it's up to the implementation of the lock, but in general, no.

Comment: @Patrick I know I'm a bit lazy... my way I guess... I think I may continue on the assumption that locks are automatically released, and see how my program copes...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simple test may show you that lock is not released upon thread termination:

```
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class LockTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Lock l = new ReentrantLock();

        Thread t = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread()+": Acquire lock");
                l.lock();
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread()+": Lock aquired: wait");
                LockSupport.parkNanos(1_000_000_000);
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread()+"; Exiting");
            }
        };
        t.start();
        LockSupport.parkNanos(500_000_000);
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread()+": Acquire lock");
        l.lock();
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread()+"; Success!");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Thread[Thread-0,5,main]: Acquire lock
Thread[Thread-0,5,main]: Lock aquired: wait
Thread[main,5,main]: Acquire lock
Thread[Thread-0,5,main]; Exiting
// "Success" is never written: stuck in dead-lock
```

So when the separate thread acquired the lock, then exited, lock cannot be taken by main thread.

Comment: It would be nice to associate locks that have been acquired by a particular thread with that thread - the API (somewhat surprisingly) doesn't appear to do this. I suppose can hold a collection of acquired locks in a custom thread implementation and release them all just before the thread is due to finish. I don't know if this has pitfalls...

Comment: @OwenThomas, API does associate the lock with thread. You can check this trying to unlock the acquired lock from another thread: you will get an exception. Adding automatic unlock after thread finishes is too much of unnecessary work and unnecessary overhead.

Comment: Is there a method I can call on the current thread - something like getLocks() - that returns a collection containing the threads locks?

Comment: @OwenThomas, well, you can do this using something like `ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean( ).getThreadInfo(..).getLockedMonitors(..)`, but you will have not `Lock` objects themselves, but raw monitors the thread uses.

Comment: Hmmm... looks a bit unweildy... do you have an opinion on whether including such a collection in a subclass of Thread (or an implementation of Runnable or Callable) would or would not work?

Comment: @OwenThomas, I don't know the details of your problem. Probably you can just subclass the thread, take the lock as the constructor parameter, store it into field and implement `void run() {lock.lock(); try {super.run();} finally{lock.unlock();}}`, so the lock will be held the whole thread lifetime.

Comment: Thanks for your help; .it helped me find what I think will work.