# Thread dump analyser missing thread

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat, concurrency, thread-dump

I am analysing a thread dump and I have hundreds of threads in status WAITING(parking) parking to wait for  <0x00000005c1c3e0b0>.
Now I expected to find another thread having the lock on the object 0x00000005c1c3e0b0, but there is not !.
Does anyone have an explanation for that?

Note:
0x00000005c1c3e0b0 is a java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock$NonfairSync)

My theory:
Since I have many thread waiting for getting a lock to basically access a SelectableConcurrentHashMap, I expected that there was another thread executing a method of that SelectableConcurrentHashMap, having its lock. There isn't in my thread dump. Assuming my thread dump is reliable, I think that the unlock method failed. In my case ReentrantReadWriteLock.tryRelease probably failed (IllegalMonitorStateException ?).
My log system was blocked by this lock , so I have no logs to check this.
If this is true , I wonder how that happened.
If the unlock didn't fail, since there is still a lock, that would mean that the thread would still be active on the operation to do after getting the lock, but I can't see such a thread in the thread dump, hence I think unlock failed.

Example of thread waiting for the lock:

INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/10/15 10:41:04.121 | "ThreadExecutor-master-32040-TriggerTask [8796781183926]" #32040 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f73140a8000 nid=0x712c waiting on condition [0x00007f72f90e1000]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/10/15 10:41:04.121 |    java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/10/15 10:41:04.121 |     at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/10/15 10:41:04.121 |     - parking to wait for  <0x00000005c1c3e0b0> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock$NonfairSync)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/10/15 10:41:04.121 |     at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/10/15 10:41:04.121 |     at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:836)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/10/15 10:41:04.121 |     at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireShared(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:967)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/10/15 10:41:04.121 |     at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireShared(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1283)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/10/15 10:41:04.121 |     at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock$ReadLock.lock(ReentrantReadWriteLock.java:727)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/10/15 10:41:04.121 |     at net.sf.ehcache.store.chm.SelectableConcurrentHashMap$Segment.get(SelectableConcurrentHashMap.java:721)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/10/15 10:41:04.121 |     at net.sf.ehcache.store.chm.SelectableConcurrentHashMap.get(SelectableConcurrentHashMap.java:324)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/10/15 10:41:04.121 |     at net.sf.ehcache.store.MemoryStore.get(MemoryStore.java:326)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/10/15 10:41:04.122 |     at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.get(Cache.java:1734)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/10/15 10:41:04.122 |     at it.luca.example.localcache.region.impl.ehcacheRegion.getWithLoader(ehcacheRegion.java:308)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/10/15 10:41:04.122 |     at it.luca.example.localcache.DefaultCacheController.getWithLoader(DefaultCacheController.java:235)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/10/15 10:41:04.122 |     at it.luca.example.cache.impl.localcacheAdapter.getOrAddTemp(localcacheAdapter.java:212)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/10/15 10:41:04.122 |     at it.luca.example.tx.Transaction$GlobalCacheAdapter.getOrAddTemp(Transaction.java:2382)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/10/15 10:41:04.122 |     at it.luca.example.cache.AbstractCacheTemp.get(AbstractCacheTemp.java:175)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/10/15 10:41:04.122 |     at it.luca.example.Inner.InnerItemCacheTemp.getCached(InnerItemCacheTemp.java:110)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/10/15 10:41:04.122 |     at it.luca.example.core.ObjectFactory.getCachedItem(ObjectFactory.java:456)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/10/15 10:41:04.122 |     at it.luca.example.Inner.InnerSession.lookupItem(InnerSession.java:1817)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/10/15 10:41:04.122 |     at it.luca.example.Inner.InnerSession.getItem(InnerSession.java:1903)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/10/15 10:41:04.122 |     at it.luca.example.task.impl.DefaultScheduleService.getScheduledItem(DefaultScheduleService.java:1347)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/10/15 10:41:04.122 |     at it.luca.example.task.impl.DefaultScheduleService.doProcess(DefaultScheduleService.java:1398)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/10/15 10:41:04.122 |     at it.luca.example.task.impl.DefaultScheduleService.doProcessInSystem(DefaultScheduleService.java:1377)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/10/15 10:41:04.122 |     at it.luca.example.task.impl.DefaultScheduleService$5.run(DefaultScheduleService.java:1256)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/10/15 10:41:04.122 |     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/10/15 10:41:04.122 |     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/10/15 10:41:04.122 |     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/10/15 10:41:04.122 |
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/10/15 10:41:04.122 |

Comment: Please provide some details...How on earth will anybody fix the problem with so little information!!!

Comment: I don't want to know the solution to my specific problem. I want to know if there is any possible explanation why there is no thread locking an object whose lock has been waiting for.
Anyway if you have in mind any info that could be useful , I 'll try to provide it(I can't providethe full thread dump)

Comment: Since I have many thread waiting for getting a lock on basically to access a SelectableConcurrentHashMap, I expected that there was another thread executing a method of that SelectableConcurrentHashMap.

Comment: Yes, a lock can be held without owner ... according to this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33064555/does-a-thread-release-a-lock-when-it-finishes