# How can I guarantee a thread is safely unlocking a lock upon termination, while all methods already handle it?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, locking

A server project, might run for very long time and create many threads.
In the following code I ask myself do i have to protect the lock somehow in addition to an overall try catch in method `setData(MyData data)`:

note: assuming its thread-safe, i am not really familiar with other reasons or natural disasters that may cause thread termination, like windows 7 limitations or so. (i am not greedy, using +-5 threads, but still)

```
public class MyFactory {

private ReadWriteLock rwl = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
    private Lock readLock = rwl.readLock();
    private Lock writeLock = rwl.writeLock();
    
    private static MyFactory _instance = new MyFactory();
    private static Map<Integer, MyData> mapDatas = new HashMap<>();
    
    public static MyFactory getInstance() {
        return _instance;
    }
    
    
    public void setData(MyData data) {
        writeLock.lock();   
        try {
            mapData.put(...);
        } catch (Exception exc) {
            ...
        } finally {
            writeLock.unlock();
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you are so concerned you can switch to synchronized method or synchronized blocks instead of explicit locks.

Comment: although now i compare your advice to here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33064555/does-a-thread-release-a-lock-when-it-finishes/33066090#33066090

its not really different. so i am still concerned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you *never* expose the lock to other objects and you always use unlock the lock in a finally block, you are fine.

The reason is that the code in the **finally** block is *always* called if something happens in the **try** or **catch** blocks. Even if an `Error` is thrown this is true. These happen for example when you're out of memory or there is a linkage error with some DLL. If something *worse* happens than an `Error`, that will likely also end your process and make the problem moot.